# How to say “grammatical case” in Chinese?

Tags: grammar, terminology

How do you call “grammatical case” in Chinese? I mean the property of grammar where nouns change based on their function in sentence, for instance like in Russian or to lesser extent in German.

I have found 语义格 and 格语法, the second one seems better. Are there better ways to say that?

Also: how to say “case ending”?

Comment: Wikipedia:格（casus，英语：case），也叫语义格
jukuu has 1 or 2 samples with 语法格 for grammatical case, but also just 格 for "grammatical case". 1.  any grammatical case other than the nominative.
 除了主格之外的任何语法格。 Also see Wikipedia on 印欧语系, "3个数和8个格" 3 numbers and 8 cases.  case ending:变格词尾,格尾 (see bkrs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From "标准德语语法 Lehr- und Übungsbuch der deutschen Grammatik"

§ 1 名词的**变格**

带定冠词的单数名词的**变格**

```
Singular   maskulin   feminin     neutral   man fragt  
Nominativ der Vater   die Mutter das Kind   Wer? / Was?  
Akkusativ den Vater   die Mutter das Kind   Wen? / Was?  
Dativ     dem Vater   der Mutter dem Kind   Wem?  
Genitiv   des Vaters  der Mutter des Kindes Wessen?
```

变格： change case
格： case

Answer (score 1):

It is just [格](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A0%BC_(%E8%AF%AD%E6%B3%95)), while the Wikipedia page also lists 语义格 as a possibility.

格语法 is not acceptable, as it would mean a **grammar** of some kind, but not "case".

"case ending" might be 格词尾.

Comment: It seems to me that “语义格” is a bit dubious. Many sources say it means “semantic case”, which makes little sense to me. I’m a grammarian and I am not sure that it’s supposed to mean, as it describes all cases, many of which don’t have semantic functions. Thanks nevertheless :)